# Better awk formatting

Tags: awk

So I have some output, like so:

```
   Total Size:               999.4 GB (999360274432 Bytes) (exactly 1951875536 512-Byte-Units)
   Volume Free Space:        320.4 GB (320392282112 Bytes) (exactly 625766176 512-Byte-Units)
```

And I'd like to awk it to:

```
Total Size: 999.4 GB
Free Space: 320.4 GB
```

But using `awk '{ print $1 " " $2 " " $3 " " $4 }'` removes the second 'GB' since the first line has four fields to return, the second line has five.

I know there must be a better, more awk-ish way than using substr:

```
awk '{ print substr( $0, 0, 37 ) }'
```

(which gets me close).

Or should I be using sed?

Comment: Using `sed` is trivial: `sed 's/ (.*//'` (replace everything from blank open bracket to end of line with nothing).  When dealing with fixed columnar layouts, using `substr()` is not necessarily incorrect.  `awk` excels at variable-width fields in formats.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works by changing the field separator to `:` or `(`:

```
$ awk -F'[:(]' '{ print $1":"$2 }' file
Total Size:               999.4 GB 
Volume Free Space:        320.4 GB
```

If you want to remove `Volume`:

```
$ awk -F' *[:(] *' '{ sub(/^ *(Volume)? */, ""); printf "%-10s: %s\n",$1,$2 }' file
Total Size: 999.4 GB
Free Space: 320.4 GB
```

The above will need to be altered if your input has not just spaces but also tabs.  In that case:

```
$ awk -F' *[:(][[:space:]]*' '{ sub(/^[[:space:]]*(Volume)?[[:space:]]*/, ""); printf "%-10s: %s\n",$1,$2 }' file
Total Size: 999.4 GB
Free Space: 320.4 GB
```

#### Addendum: calculating percent free space

```
$ awk -F' *[:(][[:space:]]*' '/Size/{s=$2} /Free/{f=$2} END{ printf "Total Size: %s\nFree Space: %s\nRatio:      %s%%\n",s,f,100*f/s }' file
Total Size: 999.4 GB
Free Space: 320.4 GB
Ratio:      32.0592%
```

Comment: How about to add a new line of Percent Free, something like: `printf "%.2f" $2/$1*100 `?  I know I could pipe it into another `awk` but would prefer to use `printf` effectively.

Comment: @da4 I just added code to calculate percent free space.

Answer (score 0):

Tell awk to use a different field separator. In this instance, you have a colon that separates your text from the values. In effect, the colon becomes your field separator:

```
cat <content> | awk -F: '{ print $1 $2 }'
```

Then field $1 contains the leading text, while field $2 contains everything after.

Comment: Note that only part of $2 is wanted, so you've missed the objective of the question.